# What is the BlackBerry Messenger or BBM instant messaging User agent string?

Tags: user-agent, instant-messaging

**What is the BlackBerry Messenger or BBM instant messaging' User agent string ?** 
plz any one post user agent string for bbm instant messaging ?

Comment: A simple google search for Blackberry user agents turned up this list: http://www.useragentstring.com/pages/BlackBerry/

Answer (score 0):

BlackBerry 10 user agent string is:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (BB10; <Device Model>) AppleWebKit/<WebKit Version> (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/<BB Version #> Mobile Safari/<WebKit Version>
```

Unless your asking what a BBM Pin is? In which case, the UAString is just an 8 digit hexadecimal code assigned by the BBM server